# Using xopendisplay in ARM getting segmentation fault

Tags: segmentation-fault, arm, x11, xlib

1. I currently did a sample multi threaded code using Xlib and sdl to
   make two separate child windows. It works well in X86 architecture.
   I    cross compiled same code for ARM using
   arm-poky-linux-gnueabi-gcc-4.8.3 and built executables. I tried this
   executables in R CAR-E2 Board, some errors occurred. Mostly
   segmentation fault occurred. Some times, window got created using
   xlib, persists for a very short time and exits, while window created
   using sdl works successfully. I already set DISPLAY environment
   variables to :0.0 and crosschecked. When the  program was debugged, 
   it was found that Xopendisplay makes this error.

Is XAUTHORITY environment variable making such issue?

When I checked XAUTHORITY variable, it was not set (Xauthority file was not found)

For debugging purpose i wrote a sample application for ARM.

```
  #include <X11/Xlib.h>
  #include <stdio.h>

   int main()
 {
   Display *display;
   if(!(display=XOpenDisplay(NULL)))
   {
     return(1);
   }
  return 0;
}
```

Still I am getting "segmentation Fault" at XopenDisplay() in ARM.
.Please anyone suggest a solution for this problem.

Comment: Sounds like a threading issue... Do you call XInitThreads properly? https://tronche.com/gui/x/xlib/display/XInitThreads.html

Comment: Thanks Andreas. The same code running successfully in x86 platform. I locked and unlocked threads currectly  in program. When i executed same program as super  user in x86,got errors  like segmentation fault and no protocol found. So i set xhost+localuser:$USER. Then super user got authentication from Xserver and program executed successfully. In ARM platform, the same program  getting segmentation fault and i didnt find x authentication.  Please help me to find root cause of this prblem. Thanks all.